# select query not executing

Tags: iphone, sqlite

When i am trying to execute select query not executing .

after the below line of code execution of program stopped.

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from maintable_master where din =? ",din];
```

Comment: provide few more lines of code.

Comment: Please do not CLCIK the "UP/DOWN" arrows just for fun, OR at least study the stackoverflow to find out that when & how to use them?

what special thing in this question forced you to give it +1??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if din is integer then,

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from maintable_master where din =%d ",din];
```

and if din is string then,

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from maintable_master where din ='%@' ",din];
```

Answer (score 0):

Din must me an nsstring, what is the object type of din

if it is int, please wrap it in an NSString